# Jquery Hide with asp.net postback

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

I have the following code.....

```
<head>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/hidepanel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="outboundForm">
    <p>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" ClientIDMode="Inherit" runat="server" TabIndex="17" CssClass="btnSubmit"
            OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" meta:resourcekey="btnSubmitResource1" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnReset" runat="server" CssClass="btnReset" OnClick="btnReset_Click"
            meta:resourcekey="btnResetResource1" />
    </p>
</div>
<div id="MailPreviewDiv">
    <asp:Label ID="lblPreview" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="" />
</div>
```

my hidepanel.js looks like this....

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    d = new Date();
    d = d.getTime();
    if ($('#reloadValue').val().length == 0) {
        $('#reloadValue').val(d);
        $('#MailPreviewDiv').
    } else {
        $('#reloadValue').val('');
    }

    $('#MainContent_btnSubmit').click(function () {
        $('#outboundForm').hide("slow");
        $('#MailPreviewDiv').show("slow");
    });
});
```

Now, by default i would like `MailPreviewDiv` to be hidden and ONLY when i click `btn_submit` do i want the `MailPreviewDiv` to be seen. this works fins with traditional HTML but as soon as i add this to .NET crazy things happen. When i click submit i can see the transition take place but then i am left with both div's still being displayed and the `outboundForm` div is still visible.

What i have observed is that the javascript even gets fired and then after my .net mouse click even is fired, after which i can see a transition and am left with both div's visible. Can anybody offer some advice please...

This may have something to do with a partial postback happening but i am not sure....

Comment: Do you want a postback to happen? You are using asp.net button that perform postback and reload the page. Put an html item with client code only.

Comment: @AmiramKorach - I would like both the postback and js event to happen.

Comment: If this is the case, consider applying the js code after the postback with RegisterStartupStript http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx

Comment: @AmiramKorach - hey that worked a treat cant believe i didnt think of that sooner!! thanks if you make it a real answer i shall upvote this!

Comment: Converting to answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You page is performing a postback so all html elements immediately loose the jquery effect. You need to register the js code in server side after the postback with RegisterStartupScript
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try setting outboundForm to runat="server" and in the server-side setting it's visibility to false.

```
<div runat="server" id="outboundForm" >
```

Code-behind

```
outboundForm.Visible = false;
```

It seems that the JS is running fine, but that the server is reloading the hidden div on the postback.

Your JS has a syntax error  $('#MailPreviewDiv'). <-- incomplete

But I assume that's because you were simplifying for posting here.